# C# Sorting Linked List

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Using the example/tutorial [here](http://www.functionx.com/csharp1/examples/linkedlist.htm) how would one sort this list by Part Number?. Currently the list is simply printed in order of user addition:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < Parts.Count; i++)
    {
        CarPart part = Parts.Retrieve(i);
        Console.WriteLine("\nCar Part Information");
        Console.WriteLine("Part #:      {0}", part.PartNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", part.PartName);
        Console.WriteLine("Unit Price:  {0:C}", part.UnitPrice);
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement sorting, or how to use existing .NET framework sorting methods ?

Comment: You can start by looking at some sorting algorithms. Take the selection sort, which is the easiest one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: Do you wan to sort the list, or do you want the output from your code to be sorted?

Comment: I would like to sort the list upon displaying all list items.

Comment: Why are you using a `LinkedList`? `List` is a lot faster 99% of the time.

Comment: I need to add/remove items from the middle (or similar) position in the list quickly.

Comment: Consider using a `SortedDictionary`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/f7fta44c.aspx if `PartNumber` is unique.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(part in Enumerable.Range(0,Parts.Count)
                            .Select(i => Parts.Retrieve(i))
                            .OrderBy(p => p.PartNumber))
{
        Console.WriteLine("Part #:      {0}", part.PartNumber);
}
```

But it would be better if your `ListOfParts` would return `IEnumerable<CarPart>`

It could be something like this

```
public IEnumerable<int> AllParts
{
    get
    {
        for (Current = Head; Current != null; Current = Current.Next)
        {
            yield return Current;
        }
    }
}
```

and the usage would be

```
foreach(part in Parts.AllParts.OrderBy(p => p.PartNumber))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Part #:      {0}", part.PartNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to insert and remove in the middle a lot, you could consider using a SortedDictionary, for example:

(Note: This requires PartNumber to be unique; different parts cannot have the same PartNumber)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parts = new SortedDictionary<string, CarPart>(); // Key is a string.

            var part = new CarPart{PartNumber = "NumberOne", PartName = "NameOne", UnitPrice = 100.0m};
            parts.Add(part.PartNumber, part);

            part = new CarPart{PartNumber = "NumberTwo", PartName = "NameTwo", UnitPrice = 100.0m};
            parts.Add(part.PartNumber, part);

            part = new CarPart{PartNumber = "NumberThree", PartName = "NameThree", UnitPrice = 100.0m};
            parts.Add(part.PartNumber, part);

            part = new CarPart{PartNumber = "NumberFour", PartName = "NameFour", UnitPrice = 100.0m};
            parts.Add(part.PartNumber, part);

            foreach (var p in parts)
            {
                // Part numbers printed out in *alphabetical* order (because they are strings).

                Console.WriteLine("Part number = " + p.Value.PartNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class CarPart
    {
        public string PartNumber;
        public string PartName;
        public Decimal UnitPrice;
    }
}
```